# Transaction not successfully started (while tx.commit() is surrounded by a if condition)

Tags: java, hibernate

First time that I ran into this error I've surrounded my tx.commit() with a if condition but am not sure why I am still receiving this error.

```
Struts Problem Report

Struts has detected an unhandled exception:
Messages:   
Transaction not successfully started
File:   org/hibernate/engine/transaction/spi/AbstractTransactionImpl.java
Line number:    200
Stacktraces
org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started

    org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.rollback(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:200)
```

After a product has been selected by user, in my main function I will call two functions as following.

First function to retrieve the object of selected product.
Second function to check if selected user has the product therefore it returns true if client has the product otherwise returns false;

**Function 1**

```
  ....

    Product pro = new Product();
    final Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
    try {
        final Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        try {

            pro = (Product) session.get(Product.class, id);

            if (!tx.wasCommitted()) {    
                     tx.commit();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            tx.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } finally {
        HibernateUtil.closeSession();
    }
   .....
```

**Function 2**

```
 .....
 final Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
        try {
            final Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
            try {
                User user = (User) session.get(User.class, id);

                if (!tx.wasCommitted()) {    
                       tx.commit();
                }

                if(client.hasProduct(proId)){
                         return client.getProduct(proId);
                }
                return false;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                tx.rollback();                 <<<Error is on this line
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } finally {
            HibernateUtil.closeSession();
        }
  ....
```

Comment: I think you don't need to initialize transaction with final.

Comment: @Purnendu does that mean it should not be final? or it should not be initialized at all?

Comment: initialize without final.initialize session without final too.

Comment: Have you tried this: `if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();`

Comment: @JorgeCampos thanks but I need to know what is throwing the exception from these simple codes not just handling it

Comment: Could you please post the entire stack trace?

Comment: Is this line on **function 2** calling method from function 1: `return client.getProduct(proId);` ???

Comment: @JorgeCampos no that method is separate

Comment: Does this getProduct do a `new Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();` ?

Comment: yes it does it returns the object of product

Comment: @J888 I think the hibernate is facing some problem in begining transaction so add some more debug statement before and after beginTransaction() just to check if the transaction begun so that on any other exception you can roll back it

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Transaction.isActive()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Transaction.html#isActive%28%29) method. You can wrap call to `rollback()` method with condition, checking whether transaction is still active. And the second, I'd prefer the following code:

```
final Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
try {
    final Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    // do things
    tx.commit();
} finally {
    if (tx.isActive()) {
        try {
            tx.rollback();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.log("Error rolling back transaction", e);
        }
    }
    try {
        session.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.log("Error closing session", e);
    }
}
```

Of course, code in the `finally` section better to wrap into public static method and just call it in every `finally`.

BTW, why are you doing something outside tranaction? I usually commit *after* all things get done, to achieve a better consistency and avoid `LazyInitializationException`.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that the exception you are catching in the second functions is from the code *after* the `commit()`, so you end up trying to rollback a transaction that is already committed, which is not allowed.

You could try reorganizing your code to make sure that rollback is never called after commit.  Maybe even something simple like reducing the scope of the inner try-catch:

```
final Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
try {
  final Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

  try {
    User user = (User) session.get(User.class, id);

    if (!tx.wasCommitted()) {    
      tx.commit();
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    tx.rollback();
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

  if(client.hasProduct(proId)){
    return client.getProduct(proId);
  }
  return false;
} finally {
  HibernateUtil.closeSession();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates the transaction wasn't started at the time tried to roll back - and the problem may be that you are trying to wrap a `get`, which does not alter the db state and does not leave behind garbage that needs to be committed or rolled back.  Nothing changes when you perform `select *`.

In addition to this, you may want to extract this transaction handling into a common method that is independent of the work being done, so you don't have to write this over and over again, that leaves your code open for bugs.  Basically, it seems like you are getting DB objects but then intermingling some business logic withing the same method.  Perhaps consider doing something like below:

**DB Handling Function**

```
public static <T> T getDBObject( Class<T> clazz, Serializable id ) 
    throws SQLException
{
    Session session = null;
    try
    {
        session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
        return (T)session.get( clazz, id );
    }
    finally
    {
       if ( session != null )
        {
            session.close();
        } 
    }
}
```

Now that you can pull object of the DB (note that they will be [detached](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-overview), but still valid), you can then perform work on the objects. I many not have captured exactly what you need to check, but it seems like it is something like:

**Example Comparison Function**

```
public boolean doesUserHaveProduct(Serializable userId, Serializable productId)
{
    try
    {
        User user = getDBObject(User.class, userId);
        Product product = getDBObject( Product.class, productId );

        return user.hasProduct( product );
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```